# Django get_or_create on reverse relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'd like to use `get_or_create` instead of doing this:

```
    cart = client.cart
    cartitems_cart = cart.__cartitem_set
    if not cartitems_cart.filter(item=stockitem).exists():
        cartitem = CartItem.objects.create(item=stockitem)
    else:
        cartitem = cartitems_cart.objects.get(item=stockitem)
```

is it possible somehow?

The models look like this:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(StockItem, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)


class Cart(models.Model):
    items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem, blank=True)
```

So, I need to get or create a `CartItem` that is related with a `Cart`. I'm not sure how to write that query.

Comment: @ozgur You are right. Thanks man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your design is flawed. M2M relation allows a cart item to have more than one cart when it shouldn't. You should add a FK field to CartItem model instead of adding a M2M field to Cart model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class CartItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(StockItem, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name="items")
```

so you can do the following:

```
cartitem, created = client.cart.items.get_or_create(item=stockitem)
```

or

```
cartitem, created = CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=client.cart, item=stockitem)
```

Please look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for more information regarding what other parameters `get_or_create` takes.